EF Core and memory join issue
I am trying to use the EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin nuget package with EF Core 8, but I always get an error when I try to use EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin.FromLocalList method.
I created a simple AppDbContext with one DbSet to replicate the issue and added the QueryData DbSet like MemoryJoin points out.
public class AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<QueryModelClass> QueryData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

In the API controller I just have a simple method that uses EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin.FromLocalList to demonstrate the issue:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController(AppDbContext context) : ControllerBase
{
     AppDbContext _context = context;

     [HttpGet(Name = "GetUsers")]
     public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
     {
         var tempUsers = new[]
         {
             new
             {
                 Id = (long)1,
                 IsUser = true
             }
         };

         var tempUsersDb = _context.FromLocalList(tempUsers.Distinct().ToList());

         var users = await _context.Users
             .Join(tempUsersDb, k1 => k1.Id, k2 => k2.Id, (a, b) => new { User = a, b.IsUser })
             .ToListAsync();

         return users.Select(s => s.User).ToList();
     }
}

As soon as I use the method FromLocalList, I get this exception:

Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalPropertyExtensions.GetColumnName(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty)'


It's clearly not EF8-ready. Please report the issue there.

I’m voting to close this question because the issue is that the library in question is not suitable for the environment in which it is used. We can't help here. It's up to the library builders to upgrade the code.

Any solution for this issue Method not found.

I upgraded to the latest pre-release version of MemoryJoin package and the problem was solved
